# Get email extra from new outgoing call intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing a BroadcastReceiver that responds to the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL action. Meaning, every time the user makes a new phone call - my BroadcastReceiver is called.

I want to get the **email** of the contact the user is calling.

Here are the extras I *can* get from the intent:
Bundle[{android.phone.extra.ALREADY_CALLED=false, android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER=123, android.phone.extra.ORIGINAL_URI=tel:123}]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the [Contacts API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) which allows you to look up various contact informations in different ways. And then maybe go via the [PhoneLookup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) table to quickly find a contact id for a phone number.

If you haven't used the `Contacts` API be prepared to learn some 'interesting' approaches and bear in mind that, more and less behind the scenes, it's all only about building `select` statements for DB tables. - But see for yourself: [Using contacts API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html).